# npm in Rails app, error is 'require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, npm

Ruby ruby 2.2.2p95  Rails'4.2.4'
Im uising Rails gem
[gem 'react-rails'](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails),

and I want to use the package (npm)
[react-sidenav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sidenav),
I want to run this on my Rails app,

```
<%= react_component('SideMenu') %>
```

I pasted myerb file on Rails, 
and edited to work this template[react-sidenav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sidenav)

**but**, there is error!

require is not undefined..

Of course I did these command,

```
npm init
npm install --save-dev react-sidenav
npm install -g browserify
```

For browserify, I tried compile from jsx to js file, 
but I thought this is react.js file, not nodejs file. so I realized it was wrong and acturally browserify doesnt work

error still coming,,

I dont know what to do. 
I probably get lost on the roadside.

Please give me advice..(;-(

**side_menu.js.jsx**

```
var SideNav = require("react-sidenav");

var SideMenu = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    var nav = [
            {key: 'landing', title: 'Dashboard', 'iconClassName': 'fa fa-dashboard'},
            {key: 'channels', title: 'Channels', 'iconClassName': 'fa fa-exchange'},
            {key: 'fleet', title: 'Fleet', 'iconClassName': 'fa fa-truck'},
            {key: 'products', title: 'Products', 'iconClassName': 'fa fa-cubes'},
            {key: 'inventory', title: 'Inventory', 'iconClassName': 'fa fa-database'}
        ];
    return (
        <SideNav className={"plain"} itemType="righticon" itemHeight="32px" navigation={nav}></SideNav>
      );
  }
});
```

Comment: You can use Browserify in conjunction with Reactify to achieve what you're after

Comment: But, Im using gem react-rails, that compile jsx. so I need to do that?